# Capture the same match into different groups

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a large list of keywords and the groups they belong to. Some of the same keywords belong to different groups. I need to find all the named groups.

```
msg = 'ef'
tmp = re.compile(r'(?P<ABC>ab|ef)|(?P<EFG>cd|ef)')
res = [g.groupdict() for g in tmp.finditer(msg)]
```

`[{'ABC': 'ef', 'EFG': None}]`

At the same time, I can find all the groups in the following case:

```
msg = 'cd ab cd'
```

```
[{'ABC': None, 'EFG': 'cd'}, {'ABC': 'ab', 'EFG': None}, {'ABC': None, 'EFG': 'cd'}]
```

But I don't find all the groups. How do I find all the groups ("ABC", "EFG") if there is "ef" in the text?

Comment: What is your desired result? To have the duplicate matches in several groups?

Comment: @Iain Yes, I expect the following result: `[{'ABC': 'ef', 'EFG': ef}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the same text into different groups with lookarounds:

```
(?=(?P<ABC>ab|ef)?)   # Lookahead and capture 'ab' or 'ef' into group ABC
                      # if either of them is there
(?=(?P<EFG>cd|ef)?)   # then do the same with 'cd', 'ef' and group EFG,
(?:ab|cd|ef)          # before matching the real thing: a union set of all keywords.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/74bu1d/1) (see the *Match information* panel).

Given that, writing a script to generate such a regex should be trivial:

```py
from itertools import chain
import re


keywords_by_group = {
  'ABC': ('ab', 'ef'),
  'EFG': ('cd', 'ef'),
  'HIJ': ('ef', 'hi', 'jk')
}

lookaheads = (
  f'''(?=(?P<{group}>{'|'.join(keywords)})?)'''
  for group, keywords in keywords_by_group.items()
)

regex = re.compile(
  fr'''
  {''.join(lookaheads)}
  (?:{'|'.join(set(chain(*keywords_by_group.values())))})
  ''',
  re.X
)

print(regex.pattern)

'''
(?=(?P<ABC>ab|ef)?)(?=(?P<EFG>cd|ef)?)(?=(?P<HIJ>ef|hi|jk)?)
(?:ab|cd|ef|hi|jk)
'''
```

Try it:

```
message = 'cd ab cd ef'
print([match.groupdict() for match in regex.finditer(message)])

'''
[
  {'ABC': None, 'EFG': 'cd', 'HIJ': None},
  {'ABC': 'ab', 'EFG': None, 'HIJ': None},
  {'ABC': None, 'EFG': 'cd', 'HIJ': None},
  {'ABC': 'ef', 'EFG': 'ef', 'HIJ': 'ef'}
]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a part of the string is consumed by a part of the pattern, it will not be reconsidered for a different part of the pattern. If you need to find all group-patterns, we have to use iterate this group-patterns externally:

```
import re

msg = 'ef'
patterns = {
    'ABC': r'ab|ef',
    'EFG': r'cd|ef'
}

res = {}
for group, pattern in patterns.items():
    if re.fullmatch(pattern, msg):
        res[group] = msg

print(res)  # {'ABC': 'ef', 'EFG': 'ef'}
```

Comment: Then why does it work for such a case?

`msg = 'ab cd'`
`tmp = re.compile(r'(?P<ABC>ab|ef)|(?P<EFG>cd|ef)')`
`res = [g.groupdict() for g in tmp.finditer(msg)]`


`[{'ABC': 'ab', 'EFG': None}, {'ABC': None, 'EFG': 'cd'}]`

Comment: 'ab' is matched by the first group and consumed.  'cd' is not matched by the first group but the second group only.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem by compiling the template in another way? Iterations are taking too long in time

Comment: There is a look ahead matching using `(?=...)` where `...` is the pattern that you want to match. However, this would not work. You can try.

Comment: You may compile your pattens in advance once for subsequent runs. It would be faster. You can also convert the loop into a list comprehension.